# Entity Relationship Model do I have to connect a table which is not using attributes from another table?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, uml, diagrams

I tried creating an Entity-Relationship-Model, but I just don't get if I have to connect some tables and if I have to connect all, how do I connect tables which don't use attributes from another table.

[image]

So this is how far I came, I have 1 main table "inventoryManager" and inventoryManager is getting 2 attributes from 2 other tables: "categoryIm" and "herstellerIm".

But my project is also having another table, called "imUser" imUser ist only used at the login, but have nothing to do with the other tables, no information is pasted among them.

Now I don't know how I can connect it into my model ;( 
Every time I google ERM, everything is connected, there are no "side tables" or something like that, I don't really get it.

Comment: You’re not actually naming that table “inventoryManager” in the database I hope.

Answer (score 2):

You don't connect it. It's okay like that.